# Drupal Showing (2) navigation menus after updating to latest Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-navigation

I'm seeing now (2) navigation menus on my site when I upgraded my drupal with latest core update (Drupal 7 latest).

Shown below:
[image: img]

This is showing the same links, just the first in nice styling, the other in a plain html dropdown (the undesired one)

I am using the drupal `classic` theme

I'm search in the code, through numerous menus, etc. to try to remove it and nothing seems to give.

What is causing this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Appearance, and check if you have proper settings for your menu: for odd reasons they might come up in your active theme...